# trying to find a word with seperators in string

Tags: java, android, regex

i have a full string like this - "Hello all you guys"
and i have a bad word like "all"
now i managed to find the second string in the first that's easy,
but let's say my first string is "Hello a.l.l you guys"
or "Hello a,l,l you guys"
or even "Hello a l l you guys"
is there a regex way to find it ?
what i've got so far is

```
String wordtocheck =pair.getKey().toString();
String newerstr  = "";
for(int i=0;i<wordtocheck.length();i++)
    newerstr+=wordtocheck.charAt(i)+"\\.";
Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b(newerstr)(?=\\W)").matcher(currentText.toString());
```

but it doesn't do the trick 
thanks to all helpers

Comment: Can there be `Hi a.l,l? you guys`?

Comment: yes that's a good point , it can be or even "a.l l"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may build the pattern dynamically by inserting `\W*` (=zero or more non-word chars, that is, chars that are not letters, digits or underscore) in between the characters of a keyword to search for:

```
String s = "Hello a l l you guys";
String key = "all";
String pat = "(?i)\\b" + TextUtils.join("\\W*", key.split("")) + "\\b";
System.out.println("Pattern: " + pat);
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pat).matcher(s);
if (m.find())
{
    System.out.println("Found: " + m.group());
}
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/TD8LIZ) (`String.join` is used instead of `TextUtils.join` since this is a Java demo)

If there can be non-word chars in the search words, you need to replace `\b` word boundaries with `(?<!\\S)` (the initial `\b`) and `(?!\\S)` (instead of the trailing `\b`), or remove altogether.

Comment: what about  other  bad words(all is just like a example), there can be multiple word then how you can manage ?

Comment: @mohanrathour: And what is the problem with that scenario? Did you try it? See [the online demo](https://ideone.com/QYYyX2) showing how `all you` is found in `Hello a l l you guys`.

Comment: I have just added the case insensitive embedded flag option to the regex pattern, as it was used in the OP.

Comment: A small addition: if you just want to match any non-letter in-between the symbols of the search word, you may want to replace `\\W*` (zero or more chars other than letters, digits, underscore) with `\\P{L}*` (zero or more chars other than letters).

Comment: this answer works like a charm , thank you , only change is using TextUtils.join instead of String.join in Android

Comment: i changed the start and ending to (?<!\\S) & (?!\\S) only thing missing is a case where the word is in the start of the sentence , is there a fix to that ?

Comment: But `(?<!\\S)` should work when the word is at the start. This lookbehind requires the start of string or whitespace before the keyword. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/ZQDlWH).

Comment: One thing I did not take into account: can `key` search strings contain non-word chars?

Comment: no , only letters, (?<!\\S) doesn't work in cases the key is in the forms "key" ".key" , " key" but if i do "wkey" or any other letter in the start it works                     String pat = "(?i)(?<!\\\\S)" + TextUtils.join("\\W*", key.split("")) + "(?!\\\\S)";
do i need to remove the (?i) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129441/discussion-between-yanivtwin-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Please add some test cases. You may [add them here](https://regex101.com/r/DbXR5X/1) and click *update regex* to share the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 String str="Hello .a-l l? guys";
    str=str.replaceAll("\\W",""); //replaces all non-words chars with empty string.
```

str is now **"Helloallguys"**

Comment: However, if one needs to check what the search string is found in the text, this approach won't work.